# String that includes @ leads to bad behaviour

Tags: php, save, corruption, file-put-contents, email-address

I can save any string without any problem using file_put_contents. But as soon as there's an '@' in the string the script starts an unintented download. The string is sent in a form using the post-method. The php-script contains the following line:

file_put_contents("users/testguy/email.pfl", $_POST['email']);

I expect the string (an ordinary email-address like abc@defghi.xyz) to be saved in the file "email.pfl" ('.pfl' is my alternative to '.inc' and is supposed to be short for 'profile'). But instead a pop-up window in firefox browser asks me how I wanted to proceed with that file (it says: 'Type: application/x-httpd-php'). I have absolutely no idea how this problem occurs. Again: It works flawlessly with any other string.

Comment: You are asking two different things - one is saving a file with PHP, the other is servis a file with PHP. Are you serving the *.pfl file to the user after you save it?

Comment: Can you share the exact code leading to that error?

Answer (score 0):

use `&#64;` instead of an @ sign so that it will not trigger a download

Comment: Can you explain that further? Where should that be used and why?

Comment: The @ sign is used by the users when they enter their email-addresses in a form. So, I cannot expect them to enter the alternative code.But thanks.

Comment: no using `htmlspecialchars()` you can convert the string containing the email address to one that replaces the special chars (the @ is your case) with the ascii code so that it appears correctly on the page but does not have unintended behaviors.